# How to create a dynamic grid with different column widths

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap 3 and Rails.

I have a Model called Work, with many records.

I would like to create a dynamic grid on which the column widths vary depending on its row. Something Like this:

[image]

My erb view:

```
<ul class="row">
    <% @works.each do |s| %>
        <li class="col-sm-4"><%= s.name %></li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

This way, each li element will have a col-sm-4 width everytime.

I need to tell Rails "Every 4 elements change the column width to x..."

Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
<% @works.each_with_index do |s,index| %>
        <li class="col-sm-<%= index%4 == 0 ? '4': '6' %>"><%= s.name %></li>
    <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally used your each_with_index to customize the layout as it follows:

```
           <% @services.each_with_index do |s, index| %>
                <% if index < 2 %> 
                    <li class="col-sm-6"><%= s.name %></li>
                <% elsif index.between?(2,4) %>
                    <li class="col-sm-4"><%= s.name %></li>
                <% elsif index > 4  %>
                    <li class="col-sm-6"><%= s.name %></li>
                <% end %>
            <% end %>
```

Thanks!!